# Different Action Bar for different activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create different set of items in the action bar for different activities. As example on one page I'd like a search icon, but not on other page. I'm adding items in menu.xml  and then inflate the whole page in specific activity, but I want to show only specific items....how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) function for the MenuItems. With these you can make your specific items visible / invisible like you need them in your Activities.

In the onCreateOptionsMenu() callback you will have something like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      ...
      // hide the menu item
      menu.findItem(R.id.yourItem).setVisible(false);
      ...
      return true;
  }
```

Or you can use seperat menu.xml's for your different Activities. Which would be cleaner. Because you will get rid of the code parts to handle the items you don't need.

Comment: oh @Steve Benett- I didn't know that you  can add additional menus. Thanks for tips:)

Comment: @Steve Bennett - I've googled a lot, but still can't find how to use multiple XML files. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess, I haven't read my own code enough. This is how it's done:     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {       
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 1):

To add different action bar or toolbar bar on top of your different activity, you can add them as follows sample_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

And following code in your java file which extends AppCompatActivity for eg. sample_activity.class

```
public class sample_activityextends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Enable the Up button
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }
}
```

As we have done written the code in above activity

// Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

```
    // Enable the Up button
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

this will add back or top button in you activity but for that also you need to make following changes in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".sample_activity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"></meta-data>

</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```